# Does `this` refer to where it's called from or how it's called?

Tags: javascript, this

I'm not asking what `this` is. I'm currently re-reading the **You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes** book to understand just that. But there are two places in the book where the author says two different things (at least that's what it seems like).

First definition:

> `this` binding has nothing to do with where a function is declared, but
>   has instead everything to do with the manner in which the function is
>   called.

Second definition:

> `this` is actually a binding that is made when a function is invoked,
>   and what it references is determined entirely by the call-site where
>   the function is called.

The first one explicitly states that it's not about *where* it's called from, but *how* it's called. The second one says `this` is about *where* it's called from.

To figure out what `this` resolves to, I need to look at the call site (or where the function was called from) right? Which means "what is `this`" is a where question, not a how question, right? I need to look at *where* it was called, rather than *how* it was called.

*For example:*

```
let test = {
  a: 42
}

function foo(){
  console.log(this.a);
}

foo.call(test);
```

`Foo` is called explicitly *through* test, where `this` would resolve to the `test` scope. Right? So, to answer the question "what is `this`" I have to look at where it was called from, right?

*Another example:*

```
let test = {
  a: foo,
  b: 42
}
function foo(){
  console.log(this.b);
}
test.a();
```

Here I'm calling `foo` *through* `test`, so to find out what `this` resolves to, I've to look at where `foo` was called from, right?

Again, I understand (more or less) how `this` works. I'm just confused about the written definition of it.

Comment: Your edit doesn't change my answer. In both cases, to find out what `this` is, you need to **look to *where*** it was called to **see *how*** it was called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The first one explicitly states that it's not about where it's ***called*** from ...

No, it states that it's not about where it's ***declared***.

Both statements are saying the same the thing, but I understand the confusion. When the second sentence says "determined entirely by the call-site", it is saying that because the call-site determines the ***how***. Also known as "the manner in which the function is called", which supports the first statement.

Comment: I've read through your answer and comment a couple of times over, and gone through the text in the book a few times as well. And I think then that it's both, where it was called from *and* how it was called, right? You need to find the location (call site), and you need to find out how it was called from said location, yes?

Comment: @firefiber It's the ***how*** that really affects `this`. EG. was it called with `call` or `apply`, or as a property of an object, or as a standalone function so that there is no value for `this`. *Where* it is called doesn't directly affect the value of `this`, but you do need to look at the call-site to see how it is called to know what `this` will be.